# How to get this sound?

Tags: electric-guitar, electronic-music

In this song, the guitar has very little transience especially on that first high note, almost like it's singing. How would you do this? I tried messing around with a compressor, but I can't seem to get it to sound like this - almost like a violin. Any ideas?

Comment: This is some amazing playing. I think it is in his hands and not the result of outboard effects. He has amazing finesse and dynamics and he either taps or lightly plucks some of the notes so you don’t hear a sharp attack.

Comment: First impression was expecting a pitch shifter, but it appears he's playing a beautiful and very skilful tapping style with subtle bends and harmonics. It's wonderful, and a wonderful reminder that a guitar in and of itself is capable of some of the harmonic effects a pitch shift pedal would typically be reached for.

Comment: Also, where he is plucking - between the neck pickup and the neck itself - removes a lot of higher harmonics, especially when using the neck pickup only.

Comment: Yeah I think @DoktorMayhem 's right about where he's picking, if you pick on a harmonic node (like halfway along the string between the bridge and where it's fretted) you can get that soft bell quality to the sound - I think that's why the first note sounds that way. Otherwise he uses a lot of tapping and slurs that have a soft attack, he plays a lot of math rock-y stuff so his setup is pretty geared towards that smooth, compressed, articulate clean sound that really brings out the nuances in his playing. (Also don't look up how long he's been playing guitar!)